# How to do "Type Definition"

Tags: c++, typedef, code-organization

I'm using a math library Eigen and I use a lot of dynamic `vector` with a template type `Eigen::Vector<T, -1, 1>` in a lot of files. With this notation my code is really dense, so I have two questions :

Should I do a type definition in order to get a shorter and more proper code using `Vector<T> = Eigen::Vector<T, -1, 1>`? But my code will be more difficult to understand with this modification.

And If I do this type definition, where should I do? Because I use an external library (Eigen) modifying the library files is not a good solution, but a custom file just for this looks dirty.

Comment: Personally I like to use the fully qualified name unless it is really verbose.

Comment: Use domain-specific names for such custom types. Having `Vector<T>` would be utterly obscure. But if, for instance, you had a type that always represented a given physical entity (e.g. “force”), it would help readability to define it as `template <typename T> using force_vector_t = Eigen::Vector<T, something>` (totally contrived example, I’ve never used the Eigen library).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn to love the verbose notation `Eigen::Vector`. That way, you know exactly what you're dealing with.

Using `using` statements, particularly in header files, tends to lead to code that's *more* difficult to read in the long run (can you ever remember which namespace you are referring to?), and also causes potential namespace clashes.

The same style applies to things from the `std` namespace.